# Progress 4GL REST webservice getting an error

Tags: web-services, rest, progress-4gl, openedge

```
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.*.
USING OpenEdge.Net.URI.
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.JsonObject.

DEFINE VARIABLE oClient AS IHTTPClient NO-UNDO.
```

i am getting an error 
Multiple markers at this line - Could not understand line 8. (196) - 
Invalid datatype specified: IHTTPClient. Specify a datatype such as 
'character' or the name of a class. (5638)"

Comment: Which version of Progress are you using?

Comment: You may need to ensure that you are using Service Pack 1 of 11.5

Answer (score 0):

The REST client isn't really provided out of the box so you need to make sure you have it in your PROPATH.

Depending on your enviroment you might need to change it in a ini-file via PROTOOLS or programatically:

```
PROPATH = PROPATH + ",C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\gui\netlib\OpenEdge.Net.pl".
```

Make sure to change the actual PATH to something that matches your installation. Also the "gui" part should be changed to tty if you're running a character client.

[Helpful knowledgebase entry](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Errors-resolving-USING-statements-for-HTTP-client)

Comment: infact i have added C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\src\netlib\OpenEdge.Net.pl as well

Comment: infact i have added C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\src\netlib\OpenEdge.Net.pl ,C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\tty\netlibOpenEdge.Net.pl

Comment: The initial comma is cruical! Also you should only need to add the one matching your setup. It will analyze the path from left to right so only the leftmost matching value will be handled when OpenEdge.Net.pl is present in several directories.

Comment: i have added using protool so my propath is first. now i have added only C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\src\netlib\OpenEdge.Net.pl and this as first propath but still  i am getting same error

Comment: And does that match where Progress is installed for you?

Comment: Yes yes otherwise it wont allow you to add propath. its matching

Comment: I really think you should have gui or tty added and not src.

Comment: can you please tell me only src i need add or gui or tty.

Comment: i have added all in propath

Comment: Only gui or tty depending on if your developing a gui client or character based client (likely gui).

Comment: i have added only gui still i am getting same error.

Comment: instead of  define variable oRequest as lHttpRequest no-undo.  i used define variable oRequest as HttpRequest no-undo. its working fine

Comment: lHttpRequest is the interface I guess. However even with lHttpRequest it worked (syntax wise) for me. Happy to see it work for you as well!